# IndexError: list index out of range Python

Tags: python, opencv, índices

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Meu código:

```
conts = conts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else conts[1]
```

Como posso corrigir este erro?

[Código completo](https://pastebin.com/R6sq1DrU)

Answer (score 1):

Este é um problema por causa da mudança do OpenCV 2.4 para o OpenCV 3, então algumas formas são utilizadas para contornar este problema, dando compatibilidade entre as versões. No seu código, isto está sendo feito da maneira errada.

#### Manter `conts = conts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else conts[1]`

Altere esta linha:

`_, conts, _ = cv2.findContours(maskFinal.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)`

para:

`conts = cv2.findContours(maskFinal.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)`

Já que `conts = conts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else conts[1]` serve para obter o valor da lista apropriada de acordo com a versão do OpenCV (2.x ou 3.x).

#### Retirar `conts = conts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else conts[1]`

Outra opção é verificar qual é a versão do OpenCV e obter a saída `contours` do tipo OutputArrayOfArrays:

Ao invés de:

```
_, conts, _ = cv2.findContours(maskFinal.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
conts = conts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else conts[1]
```

Utilize:

```
if imutils.is_cv2():
    (conts, _) = cv2.findContours(maskFinal.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                 cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

# verifica se está utilizando OpenCV 3.X
elif imutils.is_cv3():
    (_, conts, _) = cv2.findContours(maskFinal.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                    cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```