# Reconhecimento de placas - OpenCV - Tesseract

Tags: opencv, tesseract

Estou fazendo um TCC com o tema de reconhecimento de placas automotivas. Encontrei um problema ao usar a função ***pytesseract.image_to_string***. Essa função deveria converter imagem em string. tentei criar uma ***traineddata*** usando JTESSBOXEDITOR e o SERAK TESSERACT TRAINER porem não obtive sucesso, pois as não está saindo as informações certas das placas...

Gostaria de saber se alguém consegue me ajudar com esse problema. Se o problema realmente foi o trinamento ou se pode haver outros problemas.

#### EDIÇÃO:

O problema não estava 100% no treinamento e sim na qualidade da imagem.
O problema agora se tornou melhorar o tratamento dessa imagem. Essa é a que chega para extrair o texto no imagetostring. Porém, devido aos "ruídos" ela não está pegando a informação.
Se alguém souber como ajudar.
Me indicaram usar projeção de histograma para retirar os pixels indesejados...
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado por tentar ajudar.
Eu consegui resolver essa etapa.
Basicamente agora precisa melhorar a imagem que chega pra extrair a informação.

Answer (score 2):

A biblioteca `pytesseract` é utilizada para o OCR.

O `.traineddata` foi criado a partir da fonte "Mandatory", que é a utilizadas em placas automotivas e salva com o nome `Mandatory.traineddata`

#### Código

```
try:
    from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
    import Image
import cv2
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
import urllib.request


def show_image(name, img):
    cv2.imshow(name, img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)


resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://i.stack.imgur.com/davGw.jpg")
img = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
img = cv2.imdecode(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

copia = img.copy()
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

(_, conts, hierarquia) = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,2)

i=0
placa = ""
for cnt in conts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    if 2000 <= area <= 10000:
        cv2.rectangle(copia,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),3)
        roi = thresh[y-2:y+h+2, x-2:x+w+2]
        show_image('ROI', roi)
        if i<4:
            txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.fromarray(roi), lang='Mandatory', boxes=False, \
            config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
            print(txt)
            placa += txt
        else:
            txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.fromarray(roi), lang='Mandatory', boxes=False, \
            config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ')
            print(txt)
            placa += txt
        i+=1

print(placa[::-1])
show_image('Contornos', copia)
```

#### Explicação

- Carrega a imagem do imgur e converte para o formato padrão da biblioteca OpenCV

```
resp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://i.stack.imgur.com/davGw.jpg")
img = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")
img = cv2.imdecode(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

- Copia a imagem original, converte para Escala de Cinza e depois binariza.

```
copia = img.copy()
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

- Encontra os contornos da Imagem, com a flag de hierarquia `RETR_CCOMP`

`(_, conts, hierarquia) = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,2)`

- A iteração `for` em cada contorno encontrado com `cv2.findContours()`

`for cnt in conts:`

- Encontra a área de cada contorno e as fronteiras em formato de retângulo do contorno, em que são encontradas o ponto inicial `(x,y)`, a altura `h` e a largura `w`

```
area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
```

- Se a área está entre 2000 e 10000 px

`if 2000 <= area <= 10000:`

- A Região de interesse (ROI) é criada em cada contorno com um slicer e é mostrada:

`roi = thresh[y-2:y+h+2, x-2:x+w+2]`

- Como os quatro primeiros contornos são os números, pois os contornos são encontrados da direita para a esquerda, utiliza o Tesseract para dígitos nos quatro primeiros contornos:

```
    if i<4:
        txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.fromarray(roi), lang='Mandatory', boxes=False, \
        config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
        print(txt)
        placa += txt
```

- Nos outros, para letras maiúsculas:

```
    else:
        txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.fromarray(roi), lang='Mandatory', boxes=False, \
        config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ')
        print(txt)
        placa += txt
```

- Configurações de `pytesseract.image_to_string()`:

Carrega a imagem do caractere da região de interesse com `Image.fromarray(roi)`

A fonte treinada é carregada `lang='Mandatory'`

`onfig='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789'`

O psm é 10 para um caractere, pois a lista de psm é a seguinte:

```
Page segmentation modes:
  0    Orientation and script detection (OSD) only.
  1    Automatic page segmentation with OSD.
  2    Automatic page segmentation, but no OSD, or OCR.
  3    Fully automatic page segmentation, but no OSD. (Default)
  4    Assume a single column of text of variable sizes.
  5    Assume a single uniform block of vertically aligned text.
  6    Assume a single uniform block of text.
  7    Treat the image as a single text line.
  8    Treat the image as a single word.
  9    Treat the image as a single word in a circle.
 10    Treat the image as a single character.
 11    Sparse text. Find as much text as possible in no particular order.
 12    Sparse text with OSD.
 13    Raw line. Treat the image as a single text line,
                        bypassing hacks that are Tesseract-specific.
```

A de oem é 3, ou seja, a padrão. A lista enum do OCR Engine mode é:

```
  TesseractOnly           0   Run Tesseract only - fastest                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  CubeOnly                1   Run Cube only - better accuracy, but slower                                                                                                                                                                                              
  TesseractCubeCombined   2   Run both and combine results - best accuracy                                                                                                                                                                                             
  Default                 3   Specify this mode to indicate that any of the above modes should be automatically inferred from the variables in the language-specific config, or if not specified in any of the above should be set to the default OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY.
```

E o whitelist para números ou letras em maiúsculo

- Inverte a string `placa`

`print(placa[::-1])`

#### Resultado

[image: Resultado]

Saída:  `EZG3164`

> Obs.: Foi utilizado a versão 3.x de OpenCV, no caso de ser 2.x há algumas incompatibilidades. Uma delas pode ser resolvida [lendo esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/329117/75104).